# Webflux ServerHttpRequest - Get the Website Domain Name

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I get the domain name of the website making the request from the ServerHttpRequest object. The domain name as seen in the browser.

Here is what I have tried but it doesn't display the domain name from browser.

```
ServerHttpRequest requests = request.getRequest();

logger.info(requests.getRemoteAddress());
logger.info(requests.getRemoteAddress().getHostName()); 
logger.info(requests.getHeaders().getOrEmpty("origin").get(0)); 
logger.info(requests.getHeaders().getOrEmpty("referer").get(0));
```

All those are not successful. Sometimes I see the domain in the "origin" field of Header or in the "referer" field and sometimes I do not. It is not consistently showing it... How can I get consistently the domain name of the website making the request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get host name based on IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806523/how-to-get-host-name-based-on-ip-address)

Comment: [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3371879/592355)

Comment: (assuming known host names only;)